# momentjs UTC not converting with fromNow

Tags: timezone, momentjs, nodes

This is most likely something I am missing but I have the following code:

```
console.log(results[0].get('updatedAt'));
data.currentBalanceLastUpdated = moment.utc(results[0].get('updatedAt')).fromNow();
```

The console log outputs: 2019-03-31T21:09:11.612Z which from my understanding should be UTC declared for moment to convert from. However, when I do this, my data.currentBalanceLastUpdated comes out to be "5 hours ago) and it shouldn't be as I just updated it a few minutes ago.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, but perhaps try also logging `moment.utc().format()` so you can see the current UTC time.  I think then you'll find they are indeed 5 hours apart.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the input time is in UTC or local time, it doesn't really matter. If it happened 5 minutes ago, it happened 5 minutes ago regardless of timezone, and moment should get this right.

If you are getting a result that's different from what you expect, I would say it's more likely that you're storing it incorrectly.